# XML XQuery Multiple Child Elements

Tags: xml, xquery

I need to find a way to see whether parent element has more than one child element using XQuery

```
let $d:=doc("/Users/stefan.kenyon/company.xml")
for $e in $d/companyDB/employees/employee[dependents]
return $e/lname
```

That is my query, and it returns all employees with dependents.

What I need help with is how to sort the employees by how many dependents they have. So the modified query will return

Employee #1

```
<dependent>
      <dependentName>Michael</dependentName>
      <sex>M</sex>
      <dob>01-JAN-1978</dob>
      <relationship>Son</relationship>
    </dependent>
    <dependent>
      <dependentName>Alice</dependentName>
      <sex>F</sex>
      <dob>31-DEC-1978</dob>
      <relationship>Daughter</relationship>
    </dependent>
<dependent>
```

Who has two dependents,

But NOT return

Employee #2

```
<dependents>
    <dependent>
      <dependentName>Johnny</dependentName>
      <sex>M</sex>
      <dob>04-APR-1997</dob>
      <relationship>Son</relationship>
    </dependent>
<dependent>
```

Who only has one dependent.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your sample XML input...

Comment: And did you want to select employee that has more than one dependent only or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your input samples is well-formed XML, so we have to do some guesswork. But the simplest way to test whether there are two or more dependents is to test whether dependent[2] exists, which gives you something like:

```
for $e in $d/companyDB/employees/employee[dependents/dependent[2]]
```

If you prefer something more readable, you might prefer

```
for $e in $d/companyDB/employees/employee[count(dependents/dependent) ge 2]
```